# Google Cloud Storage write with REST API throws "billing not enabled" error for new bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm attempting to upload files to a GCS bucket from my server. This works perfectly fine for the app engine bucket Google App Engine created for the project but if I create a new bucket and attempt to write to that bucket I get the following :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The account for bucket \"flow-292019-cdn\" has not enabled billing.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The account for bucket \"test-project-cdn\" has not enabled billing.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "accountDisabled",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

All permissions are exactly the same in the configuration. Billing is definitely enabled for the project. I'm at a loss on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to follow the official documentation for your use case :

[Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting)

> 403: Account Disabled Issue: I tried to create a bucket but got a 403
> Account Disabled error.
>
> Solution: This error indicates that you have not yet turned on billing
> for the associated project. For steps for enabling billing, see Enable
> billing for a project.
>
> If billing is turned on and you continue to receive this error
> message, you can reach out to support with your project ID and a
> description of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said the billing is enabled and buckets created by Google itself for the same project do work from the same instance.

Comment: Then I would recommend to contact [GCP Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346).